# Using the Jordan Curve Theorem.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Suppose $y_1, y_2$ are simple closed taxicab paths with their images completely disjoint $Im(y_1) \cap Im(y_2) = \emptyset$.

Let $Y_1, Y_2$ be the bounded components of $y_1, y_2$ respectively. I want to show that $cl(Y_1) \cap cl(Y_2) = \emptyset $  or $cl(Y_1) \subset Y_2$ or $cl(Y_2) \subset Y_1$?

If someone could verify this reasoning, it would be great.

Basically there are two cases,

(1) $Im(y_1)$ is inside $Im(y_2)$ with $Im(y_1) \cap Im(y_2) = \emptyset$. (remember these are curves).

So that it immediately (I don't know how else to convince this is true) follows $cl(Y_1) \subset Y_2$ or $cl(Y_2) \subset Y_1$ since without any loss of generality

$$cl(y_1) = Y_1 \cup Im(y_1) \subset Y_2$$

(2) $Im(y_1) \cap Im(y_2) = \emptyset$, neither sets contain the other.

In this case, we get

$cl(Y_1) \cap cl(Y_2) = (Im(y_1) \cup Y_1 ) \cap (Im(y_2) \cup Y_2) = \emptyset \cup \emptyset \cup \emptyset = \emptyset $

Comment: @Thomas, I just mean (bad notation on my part) the boundary set "enclosed" the other.

Comment: @Thomas, I removed it and changed it. Hopefully this erases the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote $C_i$ the image of $y_i$, and let's make all data clear. As $C_i$ is a Jordan curve, it is connected and disconnects the plane: the open set $U_i=\mathbb R^2\setminus C_i$ has two connected components, one $Y_i$ bounded, the other $Z_i$ unbounded. These two connected components are open sets in the plane, and have both the same boundary, namely $C_i$.

Now, $C_2$ is a *connected* set that doesn't meet $C_1$, hence it is contained in $U_1$, hence in one connected component, either $Y_1$ or $Z_1$.

Suppose $C_2\subset Y_1$, and so $C_2\cap Z_1=\varnothing$. This gives $Z_1\subset U_2$ and since $Z_1$ is connected, either $Z_1\subset Y_2$ or $Z_1\subset Z_2$. But $Y_2$ is bounded and $Z_1$ is not, hence $Z_1\subset Z_2$ and $\overline{Z_1}\subset\overline{Z_2}$. By complementation, $Y_2\subset Y_1$ and finally $\overline{Y_2}=C_2\cup Y_2\subset Y_1$.

Next suppose $C_2\subset Z_1$. Then $Y_1\subset U_2$ and (a) $Y_1\subset Y_2$ or (b) $Y_1\subset Z_2$. 
In case (a) we have $C_1\subset\overline{Y_1}\subset\overline{Y_2}=C_2\cup Y_2$, hence $C_1\subset Y_2$ and arguing as above, $\overline{Y_1}\subset Y_2$. In case (b), it is $Y_1\cap Y_2=\varnothing$, hence $\overline{Y_1}\cap Y_2=\varnothing$ ($Y_2$ is open). On the other hand, since $C_2\subset Z_1$ we have 
$\overline{Y_1}\cap C_2=\varnothing$, and we conclude $\overline{Y_1}\cap\overline{ Y_2}=\varnothing$.